# What could be the impacts on the intercept and slops of each predictor in Logistic Regression by rare event cases?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model

I am wondering how data set with rare event cases would impact on my Logistic Regression model in terms of the intercept and slopes of each predictor?